# How to reset form in redux form with reset and getForm with getFormValues

Tags: reactjs

i have a question about how to reset field via action cancel and after click button add again the form will be reset.

this is my container

client.js

```
actionBatalAdd = (event) => {
      event.preventDefault();
      this.props.hideModalAdd()    
      this.props.resetField;
    }
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    ...state.locale,
    ...state.client,
    layoutData: { ...state.layout },
    resetField : reset("add-client"),
    formValue: getFormValues('edit-client')(state),
    formValue2 : getFormValues('add-client')(state),
});
```

i already try with reset from redux-form, but still no change, when i try to typing any character and then i press the cancel button, and after that i press the button add, the character still there, still no reset.

Comment: Add `()` to you resetField and see what happens. Like so: `this.props.resetField();`

Comment: it fixed now. now the problem is when i click button cancel or update in edit button, and after that i click button add, the form in edit appear to in addform